# Updating a notebook in Kaggle

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kaggle

I currently have a notebook I've been working on locally, and I pushed it to kaggle with the command in terminal:

`> kaggle kernels push -p real_estate`

Everything worked fine the first time I pushed it, but now that I updated the code in the notebook, when I run the command again I get the error:

```
409 - Conflict - The requested title "real_estate_clustering" is already in use by a kernel. Please choose another title.
```

I understand the error is coming up because I have the title real_estate_clustering in my kernel-metadata.json and this title was used the first time I pushed the notebook. However, how would I go about updating the notebook with progress/changes that I've made. Do I have to define a new title every time?

I understand the error is coming up because I have the title real_estate_clustering in my kernel-metadata.json and this title was used the first time I pushed the notebook. However, how would I go about updating the notebook with progress/changes that I've made. Do I have to define a new title every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you shared, there is likely an issue with the slug field in your `kernel-metadata.json` file. This happened because Kaggle "sanitizes" URL slugs, changing `_` to `-`.

There are two ways to fix this. Either you can manually edit your `kernel-metadata.json` by replacing underscore characters with dashes. Or, you can do a `kaggle kernels pull`.